# Image Processing video lectures or any other learning resources?

Tags: image-processing, bioinformatics

I am new to Image Processing. I will use Image Processing to for Medical Images. I am searching for video lectures or any other good learning resources? Any help. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Saghar Ayyaz

Answer (score 2):

Did you check in MIT open course ware.
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/health-sciences-and-technology/hst-582j-biomedical-signal-and-image-processing-spring-2007/

This is also a good one

http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_details.php?seriesid=1906978392

This one had video lectures.
http://freevideolectures.com/Subject/Signals-Systems

Comment: I could't find any video lectures from the MIt link. Do they have video lectures there?

Comment: Are you particular on video lectures?

Comment: Actually no. But I was thinking may be they have and I could't find. If they don't. Even then, they have lot of infos. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check for IP in particular, but videolectures.net is a great source of any kind of video lectures. I didn't find any downloader for their site though.